# Sharepoint Permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, sharepoint-permissions

In my site collection, only the users of 'Site members' have permission to site and other contents of the site.

Even if I break permission on a page and give a user permission, it doesn't work. The permission for all the contents are taken from 'site members' sharepoint default group.

Please suggest how to break permission and give specific permission to only one page in the site.

Answer (score 0):

Here're steps:

1.Select the page -> Manage access -> Advanced.
[image]

2.Stop Inheriting Permissions -> Select Members group -> Remove user permissions.
[image]
[image]

3.Grant the user permission.
[image]